# Azure file storage with kubernetes and spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-files

I have a Spring Boot application which runs in AKS. This spring boot application accesses files. These files are loaded from Azure file share which is mounted during deployment in AKS.

As far as I remember whenever we do deployment the azure files that we mount are present in the pods created for application.

My question now is - Is there a way to have a file poller which looks for file changes from spring boot app. We will upload the files to azure file share through portal. Can we have a way where in these new files are automatically synced with pod files?

Answer (score 0):

no, there is nothing built-in kubernetes to do that, you can use sidecar containers to do that using various techniques, like rsync, cron, etc.

also, not sure why you need to sync them, since the share is mounted already.

Comment: There could be cases where in we have new feeds coming in for the files that are already present in pod. so we are looking for ways to update files in azure file share, once we update here, new files have to be picked up by the application without pod restart. Any suggestions would help